# How to enable tab autocomplete for scripts located in ~/bin?

Tags: bash, scripts, gnome-terminal

If I put an executable in `~/bin` I can just type the first few letters of the filename and then hit `tab` to let the shell finish the rest of the name.

While this works with **executable programs**, it does not seem to work with s**hell scripts**. Is this the desired behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even scripts need the executable bit set.

Answer (score 3):

You will probably have your script named similarly (starting) like an existing application or executable in $PATH (or, as Oli mentions, you forgot to make it executable).

Another thing is that it is bad practice to use language extensions in executables in $PATH, see [this link](https://lintian.debian.org/tags/script-with-language-extension.html)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `zsh` for shell and after putting a script in `/usr/local/bin` it would not tab-complete. As hinted in another answer, I checked that the executable bit was set.

It turned out that I had to either `source ~/.zshrc` or restart my terminal (effectively logging me out and back in) to make my scripts tab-completable.

Comment: I have the same setup/problem (zsh, no autocomplete of script names in `~/bin/`) but neither restarting the terminal nor sourcing .zshrc makes the autocomplete work for me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Any one has the autocomplete problem with zsh when try to use the newly installed binary command in /usr/local/bin, it may caused by zsh using a autocomplete cache. use command `rehash` to generate a new autocomplete cache will solve the problem. It also means if you manually remove a command, you may also need to run it to update the cache.

Comment: A source of this function will add additional value to your answer.